# Can a catenative complement be a predicative complement?

Tags: complements, predicative-complements, nonfinite-clause-complementation

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 251) has this section in **Chapter 4 The clause: complements**:

> **5 Predicatives and related elements**
> A predicative complement is oriented towards a predicand, normally S in intransitives, O in transitives. In both cases it may be classified as either **depictive** or **resultative** as in [1], where double underlining marks the predicand, single underlining the predicative. 
> [image]
>
> The resultative PC typically occurs with verbs that denote a change of state. The PC denotes the state of the predicand argument at the end of the process. A depictive PC gives a property of the predicand argument at the time of the situation under consideration, without any such factor of change.

In [1'] below, the *to*-infinitivals in bold are all complements of the matrix verbs *seemed*, *found*, *came*, and *helped*.
[1'] 
*Kim seemed **to be uneasy**. He found Kim **to be intolerant**.*
*Kim came **to know the truth**. He helped Kim **to be happy**.*

In CGEL, these are called **catenative complements**. But the term **catenative** doesn't convey any syntactic function of the complements as does the term **predicative**.

Syntactically, the *to*-infinitivals in [1'] do the syntactic function of predicates. So I wonder why they are not also called **predicative complements**.

### EDIT (TL;DR)

The book says both finite and non-finite clauses can be predicative complements:

- The embedded interrogative clause can be a predicative complement (Page 977) as in:

> (1) *The main question is w̲h̲e̲t̲h̲e̲r̲ ̲w̲e̲ ̲h̲a̲v̲e̲ ̲s̲u̲f̲f̲i̲c̲i̲e̲n̲t̲ ̲e̲v̲i̲d̲e̲n̲c̲e̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲s̲e̲c̲u̲r̲e̲ ̲a̲ ̲c̲o̲n̲v̲i̲c̲t̲i̲o̲n̲.*

- The mandative clause can be a predicative complement (page 999) as in:

> (2) *The main recommendation was t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲a̲n̲ ̲o̲u̲t̲s̲i̲d̲e̲ ̲c̲o̲n̲s̲u̲l̲t̲a̲n̲t̲ ̲b̲e̲ ̲e̲n̲g̲a̲g̲e̲d̲.*

- The *to*-infinitival can be a predicative complement (Page 1207) as in:

> (3) *His goal is t̲o̲ ̲w̲i̲n̲ ̲a̲t̲ ̲a̲l̲l̲ ̲c̲o̲s̲t̲s̲.*

Below (3), it does say "[H]ere we focus on catenative complements, arguing that they cannot be systematically analysed as objects or predicative complements," but note that the *to*-infinitival in (3) is also a catenative complement as shown in (3'):

(3') *His goal is t̲o̲ ̲h̲e̲l̲p̲ ̲h̲e̲r̲ ̲(̲t̲o̲)̲ ̲w̲i̲n̲ ̲a̲t̲ ̲a̲l̲l̲ ̲c̲o̲s̲t̲s̲.*

- The gerund-participial can be a predicative complement (Pages 1251)

> (4) *I’d call that t̲a̲k̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲u̲n̲f̲a̲i̲r̲ ̲a̲d̲v̲a̲n̲t̲a̲g̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲a̲ ̲b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲n̲e̲r̲.* [objective predicative comp]

Re (4), it says on the next page:

> Finally, [(4)] is a further case of the complex-transitive construction, but this time the gerund-participial is in predicative function.

Again, however, note that the gerund-participial in (4) is also a catenative complement as shown in (4'):

(4') *I’d call that r̲e̲c̲o̲m̲m̲e̲n̲d̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲t̲a̲k̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲u̲n̲f̲a̲i̲r̲ ̲a̲d̲v̲a̲n̲t̲a̲g̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲a̲ ̲b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲n̲e̲r̲.*

- Finally (Page 1255):

> The construction most clearly distinct from the catenative is the reversible specifying construction, where the internal complement can be a *to*-infinitival, a bare infinitival, or a gerund-participial: 
> [20] i *His intention was* (̲*f̲o̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲m̲e̲e̲t̲i̲n̲g̲*)̲ ̲*t̲o̲ ̲b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲ ̲a̲t̲ ̲s̲i̲x̲*. [to-infinitival] 
> ii *All I did was p̲r̲i̲n̲t̲ ̲o̲u̲t̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲t̲a̲b̲l̲e̲ ̲o̲f̲ ̲c̲o̲n̲t̲e̲n̲t̲s̲*. [bare infinitival]
> iii *The funniest thing was* (̲*K̲i̲m̲*)̲ ̲*t̲r̲y̲i̲n̲g̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲h̲i̲d̲e̲ ̲i̲n̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲c̲o̲a̲l̲-̲b̲o̲x̲*. [gerund-participial]

Here, the underlined gerund-participial in example [20iii] is already a catenative complement in that it has both *trying* and *hide*.

Answer (score 2):

The value of distinguishing catenative from predicative complements comes from the classification of patterns that can be applied to clauses.

For example, ***make*** at the head of a clause makes possible both predicative complements and plain infinitival catenative complements, whereas ***become*** takes only predicative complements.

Predicative complements are either ascriptive or specifying - that is, they express an A=B relationship with the predicand and the predicate. This contrasts with catenative complements in which the idea of 'predication' is different, one in which there is a subject or object and a catenative complement clause which takes that as its implied subject, but is not a quality or the referent of that subject or object.

> The plan was to get there early.
>
> The plan = to get there early
>
> *To get there early* is the referent of *the plan*.

---

> He made a good chef.
>
> He = a good chef
>
> *He* is ascribed the quality of *a good chef*.

---

> He made me get the mail.
>
> me =/= get the mail
>
> *I* am the one who ***got the mail***, but ***it*** does not ascribe a quality or clarify a referent. Neither of the following would be possible substitutes:
>
> He made me ***it***.
>
> He made me ***so***.
>
> What I did is get the mail, but that's not what ***make*** is expressing.

So, no, a predicative complement is not a catenative one, at least not according to the criteria presented by CGEL.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. I understand  your answer unlike many others I've seen around here.

Comment: By "the classification of patterns that can be applied to clauses", you seem to mean "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb", which shouldn't be the reason for distinguishing different types of complements. Even within the predicative complement (PC), **_become_**, for example, takes only ascriptive PC whereas **_be_** takes both acriptive and specifying PCs.

Comment: It's only the specifying PC that expresses an A=B relationship. _She made him a good chef_ means not "he is the same as a good chef" but "he has the property of being a good chef." So, _him_ =/= _a good chef_ in the sense of the specifying PC. Therefore, even within the PC, "the idea of predication is different".

Comment: More importantly, since the terminology is "predicative complement", I don't know why only a certain idea of predication makes a complement a PC. In _Kim seemed_ (_to be_) _uneasy_, both _uneasy_ and _to be uneasy_ express the "the idea of predication". If anything, the latter expresses a more complete idea of predication.

Comment: @JK2 If the reason for distinguishing different types of complements is not to describe "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb", then what is?

Comment: You have not shown that "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb" determine "types of complements". All you said was "**_make_** at the head of a clause makes possible both predicative complements and plain infinitival catenative complements, whereas **_become_** takes only predicative complements." Simply showing an example of different verbs having different complementation patterns isn't really proving that "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb" determine "types of complements".

Comment: For example, CGEL (p245) considers these four properties when determining "object" (a type of complement): (a) Category: normally NP (b) Selective obligatoriness (c) Correspondence to passive subject (d) Position. It doesn't consider "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb".

Comment: @JK2 I don’t follow you. There are criteria for prototypical objects (and other types of complements), and then there are clause types (monotransitive, ditransitive, intransitive) based on the presence of these elements. Distinguishing different types of complements allows us to classify clause types. Yet you say this shouldn’t be the reason for distinguishing different types of complements. So, I ask again, what should the reason for doing so be? And why is it not this?

Comment: "Types of complements" determine "the complementation patterns of the matrix verb". But you're saying it the other way around: that the latter determines the former, which is not true. // See the first  part of the CGEL quote: "A predicative complement is oriented towards a predicand, normally S in intransitives, O in transitives. In both cases it may be classified as either **depictive** or **resultative** as in [1]..." In [1'] above, all the _to_-infinitival complements _are_ oriented towards a predicant (S or O: _Kim_), and they may be classified as either **depictive** or **resultative**.

Comment: @JK2 Taking only one property of a predicative complement, as defined by CGEL, and claiming that everything that has that one property is a predicative complement isn't a productive position to take. If this question is simply a nit-picking of CGEL's terminology, ignoring the full criteria they've assigned to these terms, then we're engaging in an equivocation fallacy. My answer still stands: the difference between predicative complements and catenative complements, as defined by CGEL, is a clear and useful distinction.

Comment: @DW256 Exactly. Also note that that with raising verbs like *find,* there's a clear distinction between the two patterns of complementation. "He found there to be two major problems" is fine but \*"He found there two major problems" is not, since you can't ascribe anything to the dummy *there.*

Comment: @DW256 Being oriented towards a predicand is the key property of the PC (Not just only one property). CGEL (p217) shows these examples: _Ed seemed quite competent._ _She considered Ed quite competent._ And it says this: "_Ed_ and _she_ serve to refer to or pick out particular persons, but the PC (_quite competent_) does not: rather, it denotes a property that is predicated of the person referred to by _Ed_. **This is the basis for the term ‘predicative complement’**: syntactically a PC is a complement, but semantically it characteristically has a predicative function." (Boldface mine.)

Comment: Now, in CGEL, Ch 14 Non-finite and verbless clauses, 1.7 Understood subjects (p1193): the first paragraph says "Most non-finite clauses have no subject, but the interpretation requires that we find an ‘understood subject’: characteristically, the VP represents **a semantic predicate** and we need to find **the argument that it is predicated of**." (Boldface mine.) Why can't this be the basis for calling subjectless non-finite clauses ‘predicative complement’?

Comment: @alphabet _He found there two major problems_ is ungrammatical not because _there_ cannot be a predicand but because _be_ in the existential construction is not a copula, so it can't be omitted.

Comment: @JK2 CGEL spells out their reasons for differentiating catenative complements from predicative complements and objects on p1206-1209. Note that in their explanation, they don't focus strictly on the term 'predicative' but refer to a wider range of properties that their definition of 'predicative complement' entails. No one's stopping you creating your own terminology; but this laser-like focus on a single word in the name and all its possible meanings is quite clearly not what the authors of CGEL intend with the term 'predicative complement'.

Comment: @DW256 **4.1 Non-finites in relation to NP and AdjP complements** (p1206-09) initially rejects the idea that subordinate clauses can be identified functionally with NPs, AdjPs, or AdvPs, on which I agree with CGEL. But then they change their discussion to rejecting the idea that subordinate clauses can be identified functionally with objects or PCs. Their arguments about _to_-infinitivals being unable to function as objects are convincing. But their arguments about _to_-infinitivals being unable to function as PCs are not (1207-08). Consider this along with how they initially defined the PC.